# Android sqlite check if table is empty

Tags: android, sqlite, t-sql, android-sqlite

i'm working  sqlite.i want to check if table is empty.i wrote some code but my code does not working perfect
this is a my DatabaseHelper code (function)

```
public boolean CheckGenderTableEmpty() {
    boolean isEmpty = false;
    String count = "SELECT * FROM Gender";
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
    mcursor.moveToFirst();

    if (mcursor.getCount() != 0) {
        if (!mcursor.isClosed())
        {
            mcursor.close();
            Log.e("is not empty", "is not empty");
            isEmpty=true;
        }

    } else {
        if (!mcursor.isClosed())
        {
            mcursor.close();
            Log.e(" empty", "empty");
            isEmpty=false;
        }

    }
    return isEmpty;
}
```

as i said my code does not working perfect.first  time my table is empty and i can't show log message about empty
and i call my function activity like this..

```
if(db_helper.CheckGenderTableEmpty()==true)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "is not empty",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

how i can check if database is empty in activity?

if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: use `count(*)` with rawQuery

Comment: What is `new MainActivity(getApplicationContext())` supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry i misteked.i updated my code

Comment: @chromelend: use `mcursor.moveToFirst();Log.e(" empty", "mcursor.getCount ::"+mcursor.getCount());` and check what value you are getting in log for `mcursor.getCount`

Comment: it is as simple as: `if(!mcursor.moveToFirst()) { /*table is emty*/ } else { /* iterate cursor*/}`

Comment: @ Selvin i changed my code and please show it

Comment: hehe :           `Log.e("is not empty", "is not empty");` and then `isEmpty=true;`  <= in the same `if` ... you should be more decided :P

Answer (score 1):

Use `getCount()` method of `Cursor`:

```
public boolean IsTableEmpty(Cursor cursor) {
    return !(cursor.getCount() > 0);
}
```

Comment: ... or simply one line: `return (cursor.getCount() > 0);`

Comment: or `return cursor.moveToFirst();` ... but still, cursor should be closed if you open it in the same function ...

Comment: @DerGolem: Ah, cleaner way :)

Comment: cleaner but still more methods calls ... afaik `moveToFirst()` is calling `getCount()` internaly **edit:** `public final boolean moveToFirst() {
        return moveToPosition(0);
    }` => `public final boolean moveToPosition(int position) {
        final int count = getCount(); ...` from AbstractCursor.java

Comment: @Selvin: Internally, `moveToFirst()` calls `getCount()`. So, its wise to use `getCount()` instead of `moveToFirst()`

Comment: yes, I wrote  this in my comment (and even provide the code) ... there was no *atDerGolem* in your comment first so i thought that your comment was to mine comment

Answer (score 1):

The Android framework has a [helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String%29) for this in the [DatabaseUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) class:

```java
public boolean CheckGenderTableEmpty() {
    return DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "Gender") == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can go with something like

```
SQLiteDatabase db = table.getWritableDatabase();
String count = "SELECT count(*) FROM  Gender";
Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
mcursor.moveToFirst();
int icount = mcursor.getInt(0);
if(icount>0)
//do accordingly
else
 //do accordingly
```

Comment: i changed and i can show toast message but how i can check in activity?

Comment: the same way which you were doing previously just change the logic inside method and modify according to yours need!!

Answer (score -1):

cursor.moveToFirst();                       // Always one row returned.

Then check cursor.getInt (0) == 0

if(cursor.getInt (0) == 0)                // Zero count means empty table.

Try this.

Comment: *cursor.moveToFirst(); // Always one row returned.* with query: `"SELECT * FROM Gender"` ... hahaha